# How to display image it's original size in Image control

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

[image]I tried CSS height to auto, however, the image didn't display, so I had to put a fixed-height. I Tried resize-mode and it also didn't work. I Tried adding "img-responsive" and it also didn't work.

**CSS**

```
.imgFile {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 100%;
 height: 100px;
 max-height:100%;
 margin-left: 7px;
 margin-right: 0px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-color: white;
 background-size: 100%, 100%;
}
```

**Asp.net**

```
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image image = new 
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
        image.ID = file.Name + file.Oid;
        image.Attributes.Add("class", "imgFile");
        image.Attributes.Add("class", "img-responsive");
        image.Style.Add("background-image", "'LogoHeaderHandler.axd?f=" 
    + file.Oid + "&" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + "'");
```

Comment: Some screenshots of your expected and actual results might help here.

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that you are displaying a *background image* within an `Image` control. Is there a reason you're not setting the `ImageUrl` property?

Comment: Are you sure that your CSS is being applied properly?  Setting the background-image this way will work (I just tested it), but I had to manually set the height/width to get it to display properly.   Check DevTools and make sure that your imgFile class attributes are being applied.

Comment: Also, it looks like calling Attributes.Add twice is wiping out the first class that is applied.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have 2 problems.

1)  The Attributes.Add is clearing out your imgFile class based on your current code.  If you need both, you will have to add them together in one line as follows:

```
 image.Attributes.Add("class", "imgFile img-responsive");
 //image.Attributes.Add("class", "img-responsive");
```

2)  Your CSS has the following:  background-size: 100%, 100%;   This needs to be removed to retain the "original" size of the image, otherwise it will stretch the image.

The rest of the code you have seems to give me the result you are looking for though (*granted your handler is working as expected...I did not simulate this part in my testing).

Comment: Added two styles together and removed background-size and it still doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work?   Again, I can't simulate your handler that is returning the image so you'll need to do some troubleshooting of that part.  My suggestion would be to eliminate that part of the equation until you have it working like you want.  Then you can add back and see if it breaks.   Include an image in your web application and reference it directly rather than pointing to the handler and see if that works.

Comment: It ended up that if image is used as the background then the image height can't be set to auto. I changed it to use the imageURL instead.